# Android - update widget through widget configuration activity

Tags: android, android-intent, configuration, widget, settings

So, for few last hours I was trying to make a proper Android widget, so far without success.

Issue is that my Intents aren't getting updated.

So basically, I have a configuration activity, when the widget is created, it works as it's supposed to be.

I also wanted to make a settings button, which will allow user to open the configuration activity and change some settings.

In particular I want to allow user to open some pdf files through the widget, when it's being set during right after creation of widget it's fine, but when it's being changed through the settings button only UI of widget (TextView showing which file is going to be opened), but the intent to open the file is not changed.

I was debugging code, file is properly chosen (that's why TextView get's updated properly) intent is supposed to be properly set, but it still opens the file chosen at beginning.

That's the part of my code:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent(); //intent to get the widget ID
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);


        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.wi_widget_layout); //widget layout
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.button_plan, fileCleanName); //setting text of the TextView showing pdf's name, works just fine

        File pdfFile = StorageModel.getFileForName(fileName, this); //method to get the file, while debugging, proper file is taken
        Intent openFile = StorageModel.openFile(pdfFile, this); // Intent method, returns intent to open pdf application for the given file

        openFile.putExtra("Random", Math.random() * 1000);
        //I've read somewhere Android is caching intents, so I tried it but didn't help

        PendingIntent pendingFile = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, openFile, 0);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_plan, pdfFile);

        Intent settings = new Intent(this, WidgetConfigure.class).setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE); 
        //remaking intent for the settings button
       settings.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,mAppWidgetId);
        PendingIntent settingsPending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, settings, 0);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_settings, settingsPending);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(mAppWidgetId, views);

        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone happens to come to similar issue, apparently this part of code was ok, the issue was in the method that was returning the intent to open file, even though it was very simple. 
The intent to open my pdf file was made by calling

```
     createChooser
```

method on my final intent, after return just normal intent everything is working as it should. I guess Android doesn't like to give a choice :D